# LCD Backlight doesn’t work even at 5V. Using 330 Ohm resistor

Tags: arduino-uno, lcd

I’ve been trying to make this project: https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/chummer1010/electronic-safe-with-arduino-25d039

I’m confident that I’ve assembled everything correctly, but my LCD doesn’t display characters. Other projects seem to have fixed it by changing the potentiometer but I’m not using one.

Arduino code:

```
/* 
Made by Marco Fusco
May 20, 2016
Contact me at: marcofusco111@gmail.com
*/


#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
#include <EEPROM.h>
#include <Servo.h>

int address = 0;
static unsigned long SaveTimer;
static unsigned long SaveDelay = (30 * 1000); 


char CODE[10] = "1234E"; 
char Str[10]; 
char CodeLength = 4;
int Pos = 0;
bool Unlocked;
static unsigned long DisplayTimer; 
static unsigned long DisplayDelay = 200;

LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 9, 8, 7, 6); 


int buttonPin1 = 2;   
int buttonPin2 = 3;
int buttonPin3 = 4;
int buttonPin4 = 5;

int enterbutton = 10; 
int clearlockbutton = 13;

Servo myServo;

void setup() {

  myServo.attach(A1);

  int EEPROMCodeOK = true;
  for (Pos = 0; Pos <= (CodeLength); Pos++) {
    Str[Pos] =  EEPROM.read(Pos);
    if (!(strrchr("1123456789", Str[Pos]))) { 
      // not a valid code
      EEPROMCodeOK = false;
    }
  }
  Pos++;
  Str[Pos] =  EEPROM.read(Pos); 
  if (Str[CodeLength + 1] != 'E') EEPROMCodeOK = false; 
  if (EEPROMCodeOK) {
    Str[CodeLength + 2] = '\0';
    strncpy(CODE, Str, CodeLength + 1);
  }
  ClearCode();

  pinMode(buttonPin1, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(buttonPin2, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(buttonPin3, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(buttonPin4, INPUT_PULLUP);

  pinMode(enterbutton, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(clearlockbutton, INPUT_PULLUP);

  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  lcd.print("Hello.");
  delay(2000);
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  lcd.print("Password:");

  DisplayTimer = millis() + 200;
}


void loop() {

  Lock();

  Pos = constrain(Pos, 0, CodeLength);

  int buttonState1 = digitalRead(buttonPin1);  
  int buttonState2 = digitalRead(buttonPin2);
  int buttonState3 = digitalRead(buttonPin3);
  int buttonState4 = digitalRead(buttonPin4);

  int clButtonState = digitalRead(clearlockbutton);
  int enterButtonState = digitalRead(enterbutton);

  lcd.setCursor(9, 0);

  if (buttonState1 == LOW) {
    Str[Pos] = '1';
    Pos++;
    Str[Pos] = '\0';
    delay(250); 
    while (digitalRead(buttonPin1) == LOW); 

  }

  else if (buttonState2 == LOW) {
    Str[Pos] = '2';
    Pos++;
    Str[Pos] = '\0';
    delay(250); 
    while (digitalRead(buttonPin2) == LOW);

  }

  else if (buttonState3 == LOW) {
    Str[Pos] = '3';
    Pos++;
    Str[Pos] = '\0';
    delay(250); 
    while (digitalRead(buttonPin3) == LOW);
  }

  else if (buttonState4 == LOW) {
    Str[Pos] = '4';
    Pos++;
    Str[Pos] = '\0';
    delay(250); 
    while (digitalRead(buttonPin4) == LOW); 

  }
  else if (enterButtonState == LOW) {
    Str[Pos] = 'E';
    Pos++;
    Str[Pos] = '\0';
    delay(250);
    while (digitalRead(buttonPin1) == LOW); 
     if (strcmp (Str,CODE) == 0) {
      Unlocked = true;
      lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
      lcd.print(" Access Granted");
      delay(2000);
      lcd.clear();
      lcd.print("    Unlocked");
    } 
    else if (SaveTimer > millis() && (Pos + 1) == CodeLength) { 

      strcpy(CODE, Str);
      for (Pos = 0; Pos <= (CodeLength + 1); Pos++) {
        EEPROM.write(Pos, Str[Pos]);
      }
      lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
      lcd.print("Saving Code:");
      lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
      lcd.print(Str);

      Unlocked = true;
    }

    else { 

      lcd.clear();
      lcd.print(" Access Denied.");
      delay(2000);
      lcd.clear();
      lcd.print("Password:");

    }

    while (Unlocked) {
      Unlock();
      if (digitalRead(clearlockbutton) == LOW) {
        delay(200);
        lcd.clear();
        lcd.print("     Locked");
        delay(2000);
        lcd.clear();
        Unlocked = false;
        SaveTimer = millis() + 30000;
      }
    }

    ClearCode();


  }

  else if (clButtonState == LOW) {
    delay(500);

    while (clearlockbutton == LOW);
    if ((millis() - SaveTimer) > 4500) {

    }

    ClearCode();

  }

  if ( (long)( millis() - DisplayTimer ) >= 0) {
    DisplayTimer += DisplayDelay;
    lcd.setCursor(9, 0); 
    lcd.print(Str);
    lcd.print("     ");

  }
}

void ClearCode() {

  Pos = 0;
  Str[Pos] = '\0';
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  lcd.print("Password:");
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  lcd.print("          ");

}

void Unlock() {

  myServo.write(150);

}

void Lock() {

  myServo.write(50);

}
```

Comment: `but I’m not using one`; why don't your? You can't just leave out parts of a circuit and expect it to still work. If you don't have any potentiometers, you test out combinations of two resistors, till the contrast is good. Lastly the question in the title has nothing to do with the question in the rest of the text.

Answer (score 2):

Please add a foto of the display. Most likely you have problem with a contrast. Schematic at the link you've provided is very strange: pin 3, which is responsible for the contrast, is tied directly to GND, which sets the display to the minimum contrast. You should use either a potentiometer, or a voltage divider for this pin.

Comment: The 1602 displays I used so far worked well with either a 2k or a 5k resistor between the contrast pin and GND, depending on the model.

Comment: That's very strange for me, frankly speaking. All I've seen need some voltage on this pin, and it can't obviously be set by any single resistor. I2C adapters also have a small potentiomenter built on the PCB

Comment: That's what I had thought as well. I'm using both as regular 4-bit parallel displays. The 2k one is included in the "Elegoo Uno R3 Ultimate Starter Kit". The 5k ones are "GE-C1602B-TMI-JT/R" from "Gleichmann", which I used for work projects.

Comment: @towe for the chinese one from the starter kit there's no datasheet of course, but for the second I've found one: http://www.produktinfo.conrad.com/datenblaetter/175000-199999/183045-da-01-en-LCD_MODUL_16X2_LED_GE_C1602B_TMI_JT_R.pdf. It clearly states on a page 5, that you should use a pot in 10-20k range with the output on pin VO. On the bottom of the page there's a electrical scheme for that. Table states that at room temperature typical VO voltage is 3.7V.

Comment: With the 5.1k Ohm resistor to ground and a 5V Vcc, I get 1.08 V on VO and perfect contrast.

Comment: @towe first, this is contradictory to what is stated in the datasheet, and so is very strange. Second, I still don't get it. In order to get 1.08V out of 5.0V you need a couple of resistors. If one of them is 5.1k, then another one should be about 18.5k. please show your actual setup

Comment: I'm well aware of that. I just used what worked reliably. Custom PCB (so I was happy not to waste space for a pot), GND on GND, 5V as Vcc (either from an Uno over USB, or a Recom R-785.0-0.5), and a resistor of 5.1 kOhm from VO to GND.
The backlight is powered by either a 3.3V regulator directly (first version) or through a 100 Ohm resistor from 5V.

Answer (score 0):

Start with the Liquid Crystal, HelloWorld, Example.   Find out if it's your pin configuration or pot/no pot issue, or if you have a doofed LCD.

Some LCD 1602 have an on board pot, so make sure that's not there too.

Process of elimination.